# Networkx inverts some edges' order in nx.Graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have an issue with networkx (Python 2.7): some points coordinates are inverted after having been passed in a graph.

Here is an example:

```
inputdata= [('766', '7628'),
 ('7233', '7369'),
 ('7233', '7575'),
 ('7233', '7576'),
 ('7233', '7577'),
 ('7235', '7236'),
 ('7369', '7575'),
 ('7369', '7576'),
 ('7369', '7577'),
 ('7370', '7377'),
 ('7575', '7576'),
 ('7575', '7577'),
 ('7576', '7577'),
 ('7578', '7579'),
 ('7580', '7587'),
 ('7607', '7608'),
 ('7673', '7674'),
 ('7676', '7627'),
 ('7677', '7678'),
 ('7623', '7624'),
 ('7628', '7629'),
 ('7637', '7633')]

Gr = nx.Graph()
Gr.add_edges_from(inputdata)

Gr.edges()
Out[108]: 
[('7370', '7377'),
 ('7580', '7587'),
 ('766', '7628'),
 ('7678', '7677'),
 ('7676', '7627'),
 ('7674', '7673'),
 ('7369', '7575'),
 ('7369', '7233'),
 ('7369', '7577'),
 ('7369', '7576'),
 ('7575', '7233'),
 ('7575', '7577'),
 ('7575', '7576'),
 ('7577', '7233'),
 ('7577', '7576'),
 ('7576', '7233'),
 ('7579', '7578'),
 ('7637', '7633'),
 ('7236', '7235'),
 ('7624', '7623'),
 ('7629', '7628'),
 ('7608', '7607')]
```

See for example pair `('7607', '7608')` which is `('7608', '7607')` when calling for `Gr.edges()`.

I need to retrieve the same order as the input data.

Comment: Your choice of storing X and Y coordinates as nodes is quite strange. Aside from the fact that the coordinates must be numeric, not string literals, an X coordinate of 100 is not really the same as a Y coordinate of 100, but they will be merged into one node. What is the purpose of this unorthodox arrangement, may I wonder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order matters, you may need to consider using a directed graph

```
Gr = nx.DiGraph()
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure what the purpose of keeping the node order is.

Comment: It's because they are euclidean coordinates, I need X to be X and Y to be Y to draw them on a plane. But graph is indirect (I don't care if it goes from X to Y or Y to X, it's the same).

Comment: Interesting, can I ask what the benefit of storing these in a graph is then? It shouldn't matter in theory if this graph is directed; in fact, it could help add clarity (i.e. the edge source is always X, the edge sink is always Y)

Comment: @s.k In fact, you _do_ care, because edge direction is defined by the order of nodes, and the other way around.

Comment: @s.k - it's not clear what exactly `('7233', '7369')` means, for example.  You're using a command to add edges.  So this represents an edge between node `'7233'` and node `'7369'`.  I don't see how you would use this information to draw it on a plane....  But it seems at any rate, you care about direction.  Perhaps you don't care which direction convention is used, but you need a direction.